# Pass the data from CPU to GPU without explicitly passing it as a parameter

Tags: c, cuda, gpgpu

Is it possible to pass the data from CPU to GPU without explicitly passing it as a parameter?

I don't want to pass it as a parameter primarily for syntax sugar reasons - I have about 20 constant parameters I need to pass, and also because I successively invoke two kernels with (almost) same parameters.

I want something along the lines of

```
__constant__ int* blah;

__global__ myKernel(...){
    ... i want to use blah inside ...
}

int main(){
    ...
    cudaMalloc(...allocate blah...)
    cudaMemcpy(copy my array from CPU to blah)

}
```

Comment: Why not instead pack your parameters up into a structure? Laundering parameters through global variables should be avoided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[cudaMemcpyToSymbol](http://www.clear.rice.edu/comp422/resources/cuda/html/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g58acd070e6f9bb82d7aeee3d0b958460.html) seems to be the function you're looking for. It works similarly to [cudaMemcpy](http://www.clear.rice.edu/comp422/resources/cuda/html/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g48efa06b81cc031b2aa6fdc2e9930741.html#g48efa06b81cc031b2aa6fdc2e9930741), but with an additional 'offset' argument which looks like it'll make it easier to copy across 2D arrays.

(I'm hesitant to provide code, since I'm unable to test it - but see [this thread](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=84099) and [this post](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=30269&view=findpost&p=170088) for reference.)

Answer (score 1):

use `__device__` to apply global variables. It's similar to the way of using `__constant__`

Answer (score 1):

You can take some approaches. It depends on how you are going to use that data.

1. If your pattern access is **constant** and threads within a block read the same location, use __constant__ memory to broadcast the read requests.
2. If your pattern access is related to the neighbors of a given position, or with **random** access (not coalesced), then I'll recommend use texture memory
3. If you need **read/write** data and know the size of your array define it as __device__ blah[size] in your kernel.

In example:

```
__constant__ int c_blah[65536]; // constant memory
__device__ int g_blah[1048576]; // global memory

__global__ myKernel() {
    // ... i want to use blah inside ...
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    // get data from constant memory
    int c = c_blah[idx];
    // get data from global memory
    int g = g_blah[idx];
    // get data from texture memory
    int t = tex1Dfetch(ref, idx);
    // operate
    g_blah[idx] = c + g + t;
}


int main() {
    // declare array in host
    int c_h_blah[65536]; // and initialize it as you want
    // copy from host to constant memory
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(c_blah, c_h_blah, 65536*sizeof(int), 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    // declare other array in host
    int g_h_blah[1048576]; // and initialize it as you want
    // declare one more array in host
    int t_h_blah[1048576]; // and initialize it as you want
    // declare a texture reference
    texture<int, 1, cudaReadModeElementType> tref;
    // bind the texture to the array
    cudaBindTexture(0,tref,t_h_blah, 1048576*sizeof(int));
    // call your kernel
    mykernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>();
    // copy result from GPU to CPU memory
    cudaMemcpy(g_h_blah, g_blah, 1048576*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
}
```

You can use three arrays in the kernel without pass any parameter to the kernel. Note this is only an example of use and not an optimized use of the memory hierarchy, i.e.: Use the constant memory in this way is not recommended.

Hope this help.

Comment: Approach 3 won't work. `__device__` declarations inside a function body is illegal in CUDA.

Comment: @talonmies But we can declare the \__device__ at the global scope of the file, can't we?

Comment: yes, that will work, although it will generate compiler warnings on compute 1.x targets.

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to do that if I don't know the size of c_blah in advance? As in - I know in advance before the kernel launch, but I don't know it at the compile time.

Doing __constant__ float* c_blah, followed by cudaMalloc() and cudaMemcpyToSymbol does not seem to work too well.

Comment: @cheshire You can not allocate device memory dynamically. You need to define your device pointer int *c_blah and allocate the memory for it in the CPU.

Comment: Regarding to the previous comment. You can not allocate device memory dinamically in a kernel. Of course you can do it in the host, as you already tried with cudaMalloc() and cudaMemcpyToSymbol.